# How to thread for loop in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I'm planning to code a script for reddit auto posting. Here is how I doing the posting job with fucntion.

```
def run_bot(self):
        with open("account_details.json", 'r') as load_json:
            load_json = json.loads(load_json.read())
        
        account_count = len(load_json["account_details"])
        
        for account in range(account_count):
            username,password,client_id,client_secret,user_agent,posts_path,proxy  = auto_poster.get_accounts(current=account)
            post_count = auto_poster.getPosts(posts_path=posts_path)
            reddit_login = auto_poster.bot_login(username,password,client_id,client_secret,user_agent,proxy)
            
            for i in range(0,post_count):
                try:
                    print("Posting on: " + self.subreddits[i] + "Title: " + self.post_titles[i])
                    reddit_login.subreddit(self.subreddits[i]).submit(self.post_titles[i], url=self.post_links[i], nsfw=True)
                    random_time = random.randint(100,200)
                    print("Waiting for " + str(random_time) + " seconds")
                    time.sleep(random_time)
                except praw.exceptions.PRAWException as e:
                    print(e)
                    pass
```

However, I want all accounts start posting at the same time. With the code above, it only posts on one after the first one finished, the other account starts. How can I achive this with threads or multiprocessing? I don't know which one i have to choose tho.

Comment: `json.load(load_json)`

Comment: @OlvinRoght I'm sorry what?

Comment: What Olvin meant is: Better using the load method from json, instead reading the file and using load**s**. ;) -- But what I want to contribute is the following article which explains quite well the difference between threading and multiprocessing: https://towardsdatascience.com/multithreading-vs-multiprocessing-in-python-3afeb73e105f

Comment: @colidyre as far as i understand, multithreading is way enough for what i want to achieve. However, I could not understand how to achieve that :D

Comment: Did you try anything and what did you find doing that?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt i tried answer belove and it worked. I can send posts at the same time with multithreading

Answer (score 1):

## I will use this module:

## concurrent.futures

https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
    
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=how_many_function_you_will_run_at_same_time) as executor:
    executor.submit(function1, arg1, arg2 ...)
    executor.submit(function2, arg1, arg2 ...)
    ...
```

To choose thread or multiprocess, compared to thread, mutiprocess is more suitable for programs that require larger computing operations.

Compared with multiprocess, thread is suitable for programs that do not need complex calculations, and thread is simpler to communicate and adjust variables within the same program.

Why is this happening, imagine if you use multiprocess, let's say each python program needs 30MB RAM, if you need to open 30 processes, you need 900MB.

And if a program needs a lot of complex calculations, it is more suitable to use multiprocess, because in this way he can concentrate on the calculation in one process.

However, there is one thing to pay attention to, that is, the max_worker of ThreadPoolExecutor is recommended to be less than 35 (depending on the performance of the computer, what code you run), otherwise the computer may not be able to run.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just implemented this and it's working perfectly.